# How to pass both event and index through a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to pass this index value into the removeNote function. But It's throwing an error and I can't seem to figure it out. The same structure works in the add note but when I try to run it on remove note here I need an extra argument and I can't seem to do that.

The main method that is causing problems is that the removeNote method I just want to get the index and then it sends the data to my node.js server that removes the note from mongoDB.

[image: ErrorLog]

```
import React ,{useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'; 
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import './Notes.css'
function Notes(){

//This is just a string because we are sending just one 
//might have to make it an array at some point
const[notes , setNote] = useState(String) ; 
const[index, setIndex] = useState(); 

var dataArr = [] ; 

const [dataSet , setDataSet] = useState([]); 
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState(); 

useEffect(() =>{
    console.log("Use Effect Notes.js");

    axios.post('/api/user/notes' ).then(res=>{
        dataArr = res.data[0].notes ; 
        //console.log(dataArr) ;
        console.log(dataArr); 
        setDataSet(res.data[0].notes); 
       
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('it didnt work' + err); 
    }); 

    console.log("The array that i got ");
}, []) ;

const DataList = dataSet.map((element, index)=>{
    return <div className ="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8 text-left"> 
        <h1 style={{color:"white" , fontSize: "30px"  }}> {index}. {element}</h1>

        <button className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={removeNote(index)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
        </div>
})
/*
function settingIndex(index) {
    console.log("settingIndex" + index);
    setIndex(index)
    removeNote(event); 
}
*/

function noteDown(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var newNote ={
        notes : notes
    }

    console.log("note down " + newNote);
    axios.post('/api/user/notes/add/' , newNote).then(res=>{
        console.log(res); 
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err); 
    })
    window.location.href='/app/notes/'
}

function removeNote(event, index){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    console.log("this is removeNote" + index);
    
    axios.post('/api/user/notes/remove/', index).then(res=>{
        console.log("removing index" + index); 
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err); 
    });
    window.location.href='/app/notes/'
    }

    return(
    <div>
    <div> 
        <h1 style={{color:'white'}} > Notes </h1>
    </div> 
        <form onSubmit={noteDown}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Note" className='form-control' value={notes}  onChange={(e)=>{setNote(e.target.value)}}/>
            <input type="submit" value="AddNote" className="btn btn-primary"/> 
            
        </form> 
        <div>{DataList}</div>
    </div> 
); 
}export default Notes;
```

Comment: What you should be doing is `onClick={(event)=>removeNote(event,index)}`

Comment: One more thing, when I pass the index through it is always undefined but when I print out the index within the map function it works. I don't understand why this is a problem.

Comment: Not sure where you are printing out `index` but `map` has a callback which defines tthe value of `index` .

Comment: Could you not be ambiguous about the value of `index` being undefined.

Comment: Inside const DataList. That's where the remove note is is called.

Comment: As you yourself suggested that its  value is `undefined` please amke sure that you initialize it when you declare variable ,please use something like`useState('')`

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
<button className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={e => removeNote(e, index)}>Delete</button>
```

Comment: One more thing, when I pass the index through it is always undefined but when I print out the index within the map function it works. I don't understand why this is a problem.

Comment: @RashadArab the `index` in the `map()` function is an argument of itself that is why it works fine there, but your `removeNode()` function expects two arguments `event` and `index` and you are only passing the index